# jQuery remote validation not working on keypress, only working on focus change

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, remote-validation

I have a view model

```
public class UserRegister
    {
        [Remote("CheckUserEmail")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

There is a Register view which is strongly typed with UserRegister model.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
```

In User controller I have action Register

```
 public ActionResult Register()
        {
            UserRegister userRegister = new UserRegister();
            //// remote validation does not work on key press when the email field is not empty, 
            //// if i comment the below line or set the email as empty then remote validation works on keypress
            userRegister.Email = "abc@abc.com";
            return View(userRegister);
        }
```

Remote validation works on keypress event in forms where email is not pre-populated, but when the email field is prepopulated (above code), the remote validation (on keypress event) is not working. This is working only when focus is changed.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont know that problem but you can use jquery to validate the from by doing `"$("FormSelector").valid()`

so you can do

```
$("input[type='text'"]).keypress(function() {
  $(this).valid()
    //Or if you want to validate the whole form
  $(this).closest('form').valid()
});
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. But keen to know the root cause of the issue.